# aspnet webapi 2 response payload not displayed for HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, http-status-code-401

I have an `ActionFilterAttribute` that overrides the `OnActionExecuting`. If the user isn't authenticated I want to return and 401 Unauthorized status and a JSON object of type `Response` with a custom message and other properties

```
public class Response
{
    public Boolean Error { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Messages { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

That's what I did:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    //some code here

    var response = new Response();
    response.AddMessage(true, Util.Localization.Authentication.Validation_UserNotAuthenticated);

    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(Response), response, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
    };
}
```

When the client makes a request, that's the Response Header (from google chrome developer tools - network):

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 18 Dec 2014 13:19:12 GMT
Content-Length: 83
```

Well, the JSON with the `Response` object isn't displayed to the client.

If I only change the`HttpStatusCode` to `OK`, the JSON is displayed:

```
actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(Response), response, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
};
```

Also, if I keep the`HttpStatusCode` as `Unauthorized`, but change the `Type` to `string`, the text is displayed normally to the client:

```
actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
{
    Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(string), "test string", new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
};
```

How can I send a custom JSON object when I get a Unauthorized Http status?

Thnaks

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using the built-in AuthorizeAttribute on your controller to secure your api.  I think the reason it's not working is because the AuthorizationFilters (like AuthorizeAttribute) happen earlier in the WebApi pipeline than ActionFilters.  See here for details:

https://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/01/04/web-api-2-using-actionfilterattribute-overrideactionfiltersattribute-and-ioc-injection/

So your code never executes because the AuthorizeAttribute already failed and returned its default response (401 message with no body).

The easiest way to do what you want is to inherit a custom authorization attribute, ex MyAuthorizeAttribute, inheriting from AuthorizeAttribute and changing the way it handles errors.  Then just decorate your controllers with [MyAuthorize] instead of [Authorize].

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();

        var response = new Response();
        response.AddMessage(true, Util.Localization.Authentication.Validation_UserNotAuthenticated); 

        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            ReasonPhrase = "Unauthorized",
            Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(Response), response, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
        };


    }
}
```